# How can I convert a Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> to a List<Object>? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the last update of cloud_firestore, I get an error when I run the app with the old code. How can I convert a Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> to a List?

I have this code and I get null values:

```
Stream<List<Model>> getReviews(String id) {
try {
  return _collectionReference.doc(id).collection('reviews').orderBy('date', descending: true).snapshots().map((reviews) => reviews.docs.map((review) => Model.fromJson(review.data())));
} catch (error) {
  return error.message;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the `List<Model>` use a `get` call and await the result before returning the `List<Model>` like here:

```dart
Future<List<Model>> getReviews(String id) {
try {
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot=await _collectionReference.doc(id).collection('reviews').orderBy('date', descending: true).get();
  
  List<Model> result;
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      print(doc["first_name"]);
      result.add(Model.fromJson(review.data()));
  });
  return result;
  
} catch (error) {
  return error.message;
}
```

Make sure to call `getReviews` as asynchronous.